# Eclipse Display (Shift+Ctrl+D) and Inspect (Shift+Ctrl+I) not working

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Luna Service Release    2 (4.4.2) Build id: 20150219-0600

OS: oraclelinux-release-6Server-3.0.2.x86_64

While debugging Display (Shift+Ctrl+D) and Inspect (Shift+Ctrl+I) popups shows just for a fraction of second instead of staying open.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try turn off the "show console when std out changes"

[image]

Comment: I don't know which eclipse version are you refering to, but I don't have such option, neither that set of icons in your answer. I have Preferences > Run/Debug > Console > Show when program writes to standard out but that haven't solved the problem.

Comment: OK, the idea is that when you do "CTRL+SHIFT+D" some other view (I guess its the console) changes its content, and gets the focus...so your popup disappears.

Comment: I am using breakpoints so nothing should steal focus, even more this is Web app with log redirected to output file, so nothing goes on in console view. Though it might be that something else is stealing focus but besides main debug widow I don't see what could it be?

Comment: Maybe some exception occurs during evaluation of "CTRL+SHIFT+D". Try   evaluating expression on some other line, to check if the popup will disappear.

Comment: No, is not working anywhere. Quite interesting when I hover over variables, methods, etc. popup stays open and F2 works.